# Not able to add linerlayout in scrollview programatically in android

Tags: android, view, addition

I need to use scrollview pragmatically, while include linearlayout in scrollview its shows error like `E/AndroidRuntime(22309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.program/com.sample.program.details}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Check it out my coding :

My linearlayout which i want to add in scrollview

```
mScrollTolinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toscroll);
```

My ScrollView

```
ScrollView mScroll = new ScrollView(Appointmentdetails.this);
        mScroll.addView(mScrollTolinear);
```

To remove the view

```
mScrollTolinear.removeAllViews();
mScrollTolinear.removeView(mScrollTolinear);
```

Try to to remove the view some thing like that but no luck, have tried with google also but dint get the solution, any suggestion or help highly accepted.

My XML

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/whitebackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >

        <!-- <ScrollView -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/favscroll" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:visibility="invisible" > -->

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/toscroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/topheaderbg" >

                <ImageView
                   "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/listbutton" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/notificationicon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: your `LinearLayout` have already a parent defined in your xml file probably thats why you are getting this exception.

Comment: yes thats absolutely correct check it out my updated question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add a view which was inflated from XML file hence it already has a parent (because it is already situated in view hierarchy). Instead of the following

```
mScrollTolinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toscroll);
```

you will have to implement something like this:

```
mScrollTolinear = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, null);
```

And also keep in mind that ScrollView can only have one child view, otherwise you can get exceptions

**UPD**
Update corresponding to your comment

So in case if you want to add ScrollView to LinearLayout you will have to call:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(yourContext); //you may also want to specify LayoutParams for it
mScrollTolinear.addView(scroll);
```

I hope I've understood your comment correctly

Comment: check it out my question i have added xml file also, need to add scrollview to the second linearlayout which have id "toscroll", and this linearlayout having so many views, for example i have added some of them.

Comment: In case if you need to add a ScrollView to linear layout please see my updated answer